# How to see variables names in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am a newbie python user, I just migrated from R. Is there a function in Python like View() or ls() in R that lets you see the variables stored in the memory

Comment: But its giving me everything that I dont even need , isnt there a way to print just the names?

Comment: [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) returns a list of names in the current scope. Since everything is an object in Python, there isn't a difference (to `dir`) between an imported module and a variable holding a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `locals()` to see all the variables in the local scope or `globals()` to see everything in the global scope. To get exactly what you want:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 7
>>> foo = object
>>> [x for x in locals().keys() if not x.startswith('__')]
['re', 'x', 'y', 'foo']
```

If you also need the values:

```
>>> {key: val for key, val in locals().items() if not key.startswith('__')}
{'y': 7, 're': <module 're' from '/Users/ian/venv/lib/python2.7/re.pyc'>, 'foo': <object object at 0x103b1d0e0>, 'x': 5}
```